# How do I define 'users' variable such that they read data from my MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, passport.js

I am building a login register system using nodejs and mysql, and I have decided to use passport js for user authentication. I have also hashed passwords using bcrypt. So far, my register form is able to take data inputs from the form and store them into the database table.

Since I am just a beginner with Node, I have no idea how change the code of my authentication config file so that the data can be read from the table in the database and be authenticated from. Following is the passport-config file:

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

function initialize(passport, getUserByEmail, getUserById) {
  const authenticateUser = async (email, password, done) => {
    const user = getUserByEmail(email)
    if (user == null) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'No user with that email' })
    }

    try {
      if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
        return done(null, user)
      } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' })
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return done(e)
    }
  }

  passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, authenticateUser))
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id))
  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    return done(null, getUserById(id))
  })
}

module.exports = initialize
```

Here is the error I am receiving when logging in with the registered credentials:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Database is connected!
New user is registered! INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, password) VALUES ('w', 'w', 'w@w', '$2b$10$bRcsJON33dZ/RCWsgNdp..G.dc112XaYYTWWiX3a7/YqnXWXE70Aa')
(node:61627) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: users is not defined
    at /Users/vaidiklapalikar/Desktop/current project/server.js:30:20
    at Strategy.authenticateUser [as _verify] (/Users/vaidiklapalikar/Desktop/current project/config/passport-config.js:6:18)
    at Strategy.authenticate (/Users/vaidiklapalikar/Desktop/current project/node_modules/passport-local/lib/strategy.js:90:12)
    at attempt (/Users/vaidiklapalikar/Desktop/current project/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:366:16)
    at authenticate (/Users/vaidiklapalikar/Desktop/current project/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:367:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/vaidiklapalikar/Desktop/current project/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/vaidiklapalikar/Desktop/current project/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at checkNotAuthenticated (/Users/vaidiklapalikar/Desktop/current project/server.js:97:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/vaidiklapalikar/Desktop/current project/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/vaidiklapalikar/Desktop/current project/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
(node:61627) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:61627) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

As per my understanding, I am not using a select query to actually read data form the table and verify it through passport.js. However, I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

With the partial code that you have put here, I suspect `getUserByEmail` returns a promise.

If so, you need to put that part inside the try block too and use `await` in front of it's call.

Try `authenticateUser` to be like this,

```
const authenticateUser = async (email, password, done) => {
    try {
      const user = await getUserByEmail(email);

      if (user == null) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'No user with that email' })
      }

      if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
        return done(null, user)
      } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' })
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return done(e)
    }
  }
```

Try this, if it doesn't work, show how `initialize` is used in your other file.

All the best!